# SQL Selecting data from 3 tables using GROUP BY

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a formula to pull data from 3 tables and struggling to get it working.

I need to use the InventoryNbr from table s and do a group by, because there is many of the same InventoryNbr's, and I just want the MAX IndexListID Returned. The IndexListID is a Unique Key, so when I search on table il, I should only return 1 row.  I want to then pull the end year from that row as well as the modelnm, and use those 2 values to get the CarlineNm.  Here is my code:

```
SELECT s.InventoryNbr, MAX(s.IndexListID) AS IndexListID, il.EndYear, c.CarlineNm
FROM sysidla as s
INNER JOIN IndexList as il
ON s.IndexListID = il.IndexListID
INNER JOIN Carline as c
ON il.EndYear = c.CarlineYear
AND il.ModelNm = c.ModelNm
GROUP BY InventoryNbr
ORDER BY InventoryNbr ASC;
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
Column 'IndexList.EndYear' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Here is some sample data:

```
sysidla
InventoryNbr|IndexListID|Junk|Junk2
12345|1|x|y
12345|2|c|r
12345|3|c|e
12346|4|e|w

IndexList
ModelNm|Junk|Junk1|Junk3|EndYear|IndexListID
name1|c|f|r|2004|1
name2|c|f|r|2008|2
name3|c|f|r|2012|3
name4|c|f|r|2004|4
name5|c|f|r|2018|5

Carline
CarlineYear|CarlineNm|Junk9|ModelNm
2005|NAME|d|name1
2012|NAME22|d|name3
2005|NAME354|d|name4
2005|NAME1|d|name5
```

So for instance, this is an incomplete data sample because every IndexListID will have a match in IndexList, but I want to be able match InventoryNbr 12345 and select the max INDEXLISTID which is 3, then use 3 on IndexList to grab name3 and 2012. Then I want to use 2012 and name3 to get NAME22 From Carine.

Comment: What about the error is unclear? `il.EndYear` (and `c.CarlineNm` is not being aggregated in the `group by` so you can't select it. Whether you *want* to group by them is a different question

Comment: I am not sure I understand what it not being aggregated means. The MAX(s.IndexListID) when matched to il.IndexListID will only return 1 line, so there should only be 1 possible endYear and 1 possible ModelNm.  So I am not sure how or why I need to aggregate it.

Comment: If there is one possible EndYear and CarlineNm as you claim, then go ahead and wrap them in MAX too. The results might end up incorrect if there is more though.

Comment: But SQL doesn't know that. You need to write the `group by`

Comment: Ok, so if I change my first line to MAX(il.EndYear), MAX(c.CarlineNm) the max will only make a difference if there were more than one matches to IndexListID (Which there should not ever be)?

Comment: @Charlieface I also want to make sure that when I am matching the IndexListID's I am using the MAX(IndexListID) Grouped by InventoryNbr.  I know I am selecting the MAX, but am I using that to perform the inner join with il?

Comment: @Lzypenguin Please check my answer. Your problem should be solved.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are getting this error because, there is a problem with your `group by` and `SELECT` section . You can not select column while using group by like this. Either you have to use an aggregate function or your column should in the group by to select like this.
So,Here is a solution you can check =>

```
SELECT T.*,il.EndYear, c.CarlineNm FROM 
(SELECT s.InventoryNbr, MAX(s.IndexListID) AS IndexListID
FROM sysidla as s
GROUP BY InventoryNbr) T
INNER JOIN IndexList as il ON T.IndexListID = il.IndexListID
INNER JOIN Carline as c ON il.EndYear = c.CarlineYear AND il.ModelNm = c.ModelNm
ORDER BY T.InventoryNbr ASC;
```

**Note:** This code is not optimized. Sub-query is little slow however, you can optimize that using window function (CTE).
 Please check and let me know.

Comment: Your solution did not group my end results by InventoryNbr.  There is say 10 identical InventoryNbrs in sysidla, but each one has a unique IndexListID. So I want to groupby InventoryNbr and take the MAX IndexListID, then use that number to pull the EndYear and CarlineNm from the other two tables. Your query I have the same InvetoryNbr and IndexListID returned a hundred times with every matching year and model.

Comment: Ok. Can you update you question with data samples and desire output? :)

Comment: I just updated my origional question with samples of what my tables look like and what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Lzypenguin Just Clear One thing is your desire sample output is `InventoryNbr|IndexListID|EndYear|CarlineNm
12345,3 ,2012,NAME22
` as I can see from your sample data?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And I believe your code is actually working, or very close. I am figuring out that my IndexListID is not unique like I thought and is returning more data than I needed it to. But your answer does do what I asked, so I will mark it correct. Thanks!

Comment: oh ! finally, I was creating your data and preparing to test it. So, I can stop now. Best wishes.

Comment: Ok, so I think I found why yours doesnt return exactly the desired result, and that is because on Carline, there is sometimes multiple matches when I match the Year and Name..... Is there an easy way to modify this to just pick one, honestly any of them are fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use window functions in a subquery:

```
SELECT s.InventoryNbr, s.IndexListID, il.EndYear, c.CarlineNm
FROM (SELECT s.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY il.IndexListID ORDER BY il.IndexListID DESC) as seqnum
      FROM sysidla s
     ) s INNER JOIN
     IndexList il
     ON s.IndexListID = il.IndexListID INNER JOIN
     Carline c
     ON il.EndYear = c.CarlineYear AND
        il.ModelNm = c.ModelNm
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY InventoryNbr ASC;
```

No aggregation is needed.

Comment: When I copy/pasted your code I got the error: Incorrect syntax near 'ROW_NUMBER'.

Comment: Also, all 4 of the SELECT options at the top are red and say the multi-part identifier could not be bound.

Comment: @Lzypenguin . . . That doesn't make sense.  In your query, those are all valid columns.

Comment: I agree, they are all valid columns, but for some reason I am getting that. Now when i copy/paste your most recent edit, there is a syntax near the second ON in the 4th to last line, but the errors from the SELECT statement went away.